# get sql data based on logged in user

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

i am using Visual Studio 2010 professional and SQL server 2008 R2 express

what i am trying to do is detect who is the logged in user and display their detail in a gridview. the logged in user has used asp.net authentication, i have allowed users to access the page using the login process, they have the "user" role set to allow. the admin account can view all users in the account from a gridview, but i also want a logged in user to see their own details in the members section.

this is shown in the code-behind

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)
Session("MemberDetails") = User.Identity.Name
End Sub
```

this is in the main page

```
<asp:Gridview>
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" />
<$ many more fields here--$>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
SelectCommand="SELECT username, salutation, fname, sname, address, suburb, postcode, dayphone FROM member WHERE (username = @username)">
<SelectParameters>
<asp:SessionParameter Name="username" SessionField="MemberDetails" />
</SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

all of it should work but instead i get a blank page.

Comment: Are you using IIS or the bundled development server that comes with Visual Studio 2010? Also, can you post the part of your web.config that shows the forms authentication part? I'd like to see if you have your web.config configured correctly.

Comment: bundled dev server, here is the web.config... umm trying to post more code?

Comment: i cant add the code for another 8 hours according to the site rules, but please gather that my asp.net webconfig files for logging in and authenticating is correct, it has worked before and the file was made by creating a full site.master website

Comment: From the GridView is missing a lot of inits, like the connection with the DataSource.

Comment: Press F12. Are there any errors anywhere?

Answer (score 1):

Your GridView tag is not complete, especially `DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"`

```
<asp:Gridview runat="server" ID="gvUsers" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
<Columns>
<asp:BoundField DataField="username" HeaderText="username" />
<$ many more fields here--$>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Comment: sorry i didnt post the entirety of the gridview for brevity, but yes that line is in there. the gridview was auto-generated via the GUI when i configured the source.

i am assuming my problem is in the code-behind or in the "where username...session parameters area

Answer (score 0):

this vb code-behind fixed my problem:

```
Protected Sub SqlDataSource1_Selecting(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As SqlDataSourceSelectingEventArgs) Handles SqlDataSource1.Selecting
        e.Command.Parameters(0).Value = Me.User.Identity.Name
    End Sub
```